# iOS 8 - Force system keyboard for an input field without using secureTextEntry?

Tags: ios

First off - I am a programmer, but I am not an iOS programmer.

Is there a method, besides "secureTextEntry=YES" to force an input field to use the system keyboard?

I'm investigating an uncomfortable behavior in 1Password (I do not work for AgileBits) where all third-party keyboards are disabled app-wide.  They have an option to re-enable them, however it's buried in the advanced options and is in no way evident to a user.  If you have removed the system keyboards in lieu of a third-party keyboard, you just get an app with no keyboards at all, or only emoji (if installed).

If there's a way to designate a field as requiring the system keyboard, without it being treated as a password, I haven't been able to find it in the iOS documentation… but their doc site isn't the easiest to navigate or search.

Comment: The only purpose of secureTextEntry is to mask the entered characters, mostly needed for the textfield where input contains sensitive information which needs to be masked such as password. However, if the UITextField's secureTextEntry property sets to YES, the system keyboard will surface from the bottom as secureTextEntry property doesn't work for custom keyboard. There is no specific property AFAIK which can ask the system to make the system keyboard only keyboard to be used for the specified UITextField.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am investing the literal same thing with Lastpass. I guess people everywhere just toggle "secureTextEntry" with no regard for leaking passwords to custom keyboard.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for that issue?

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` conforms to the `UITextInputTraits` protocol. This protocol has a `keyboardType` which you can set as one of the values from the `UIKeyboardType` enum (found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIKeyboardType ). You can change this `keyboardType` in addition to choosing to hide the characters (via `secureTextEntry`).

Comment: That, however, only allows the *style* of keyboard (numeric, email, twitter, etc.), not the keyboard itself.